# Array and elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'm building an array with some elements like this :

```
var listAccordions = [];
$("#accordeon ul.sub-menu.ui-accordion").each(function() { 
listAccordions.push("#" + $(this).parent().attr('id') + " ul.sub-menu");
});
```

everything works fine here, i've got my array and it's nice, now I want to use it like this :

```
$( listAccordions ).hide();
```

but this doesn't seem to work ?

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
$(listAccordions.join(',')).hide();
```

But the reasonable question: why would you need to have such a data structure?

Comment: ok thanks, it seems to work, well about the data structure :
I need  : #myid-8798 ul.sub-menu
so i though i would do it directly in the array and also i need to compare it with an element that I don't need in the array and this element is already in this format... so...a better way ?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to loop over `listAccordions` and call `hide` for each one.

```
for (var i = 0; i < listAccordions.length; i++) {
   $(listAccordions[i]).hide();
}
```

Comment: it could be a solution also, i guess the "for" solution is even faster then the "each" too...

Answer (score 0):

`listAccordions` is in memory, not the DOM. You can add a class name to these elements, then use the class name to hide them - if you plan to use this collection for other things. Otherwise, hide them in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(listAccordions,function(i,item) {
  $("#"+item).hide();
});
```

will work. Your array is an array of strings

```
var listAccordions = [];
$("#accordeon ul.sub-menu.ui-accordion").each(function() { 
  listAccordions.push($("#" + $(this).parent().attr('id') + " ul.sub-menu"));
});

listAccordions.each(function() {
  $(this).hide()
});
```

should work too

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
$(listAccordions).each(function() {
    $(this).hide();
}
```